# which overloaded method would it use?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overloading

for example we have

```
     BaseClass myBaseObject
     InheritedClass myInheritedObject
```

and 2 overloaded methods

```
     void Do(BaseClass tmp)
        { DoA();}
     void Do(InheritedClass tmp)
        { DoB();}
```

What would this do?

```
     Do((BaseClass) myInheritedObject);
```

And is it common technique to put `DoA()` under `BaseClass`, and `DoB()` under `InheritedClass` and override `DoA()`, and merge the 2 `Do()` into 1?

```
        void Do(BaseClass tmp)
           {return tmp.DoA()}
```

Comment: first one, because type of parameter completely corresponds to its signature

Comment: Why ask when you can check for yourself in your compiler in the same amount of time it would take you to write this question?

Comment: One way is to simply check it yourself in a quick Console application...

Comment: @OferZelig: checking with a quick console application will give him the answer, but SO answers will give him the why. And understanding is better than just knowing, isn't it?

Comment: @Falanwe you're right, if that is what he had asked for. He asked "What would this do?" and not "Why is the first method being called?" which is an absolutely legitimate answer that Jon Skeet elaborated on.
And it's not just semantics, the guy actually didn't try for himself  and did not have a clue what the answer is, but rather asked in SO *what* happens and not *why* some result happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first - the second overload isn't applicable, because the compile-time type of the argument is `BaseClass` instead of `InheritedClass`, and there's no implicit conversion from `BaseClass` to `InheritedClass`.

Comment: so Do(myInheritedObject) would call DoB()?

Comment: @colinfang: Yes, assuming the *compile-time type* of `myInheritedObject` is `InheritedClass`. Of course, you can try this yourself very easily.

Comment: thx, my problem now becomes to solve this, could you plz help have a glance?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892660/how-to-improve-this-method-using-polymorphismoverloading-so-as-to-reduce-is-ty